# Binary search for last element when its in power of 2

Tags: arrays, performance, search, binary, asymptotic-complexity

I have a sorted array.

For ex. { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ,6, 7, 8 }

If I search for element 8 then it takes 4 iteration to get the result as true or false. What I have known is the running time for binary search is upper bound as O(logn) which results out to be 3 in this case.

Could somebody help me out of this confusion or correct my concept if I am wrong?

My code is as follows :

```
public static boolean BinarySearch(int[] arr, int num){    
int mid, low, high;    
int count = 0;    
low = 0; high = arr.length -1;    
while( low <= high ){    
mid = low + (high-low)/2;    
if(arr[mid] == num)    
      return true;    
else if(arr[mid]<num)    
     low = mid +1;    
else
     high = mid -1;    
}    
return false;    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of the *O* notation is to hide less significant terms in order to arrive at a simpler expression for the complexity. So even though it is correct that the complexity of binary search is *O(lg n)*, the exact expression might well be *ceil(lg n) + 1*, or even *c ceil(lg n) + b* for any *c* and *b* (the *ceil()* operation is necessary to always get an integer result from the logarithm).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I would like to add one more thing. If this is the case can't we say its o(logn) (small-o) which is more specific as it puts tighter bound on the running time since we know that only for elements with value in exact power of 2, takes lg n+1.

Comment: No. _o(lg n)_ means that the complexity in _all_ situations is better than _lg n_ (i.e., given any positive _c_, you can find a suitably small constant to multiply the actual complexity by so that the result is smaller than _c lg n_ when _n_ is greater than some other constant). Furthermore, the complexity is optimal when _n_ is of the form _2^h - 1_ (which is when you get the optimal complexity _lg (n + 1)_ in the worst case)); in other situations, it is 1 more than the formula would tell you.